# how to write predict_generator output to a file over a loop?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, imagenet

i have a large dataset of images on which i want to run the predict_generator. i cannot run on all of them at once due to memory issues. the idea is to

**feeding small set of images iteratively to generator by looping over the range of images and making predictions for it.**

**saving the predictions to a file**

**later opening the file in a loop to read all the prediction for calculating the probabilites as mentioned in the code.**

```
validation_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255).flow_from_directory(path, target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                                                        batch_size=6,shuffle=False)


print("generator built")
print (counter)
#file = open('Failed.py', 'w')
#for x in file:
 #   for i in range(counter):
  #      features = model.predict_generator(validation_generator,steps=2)



print("features found")

model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(3, 3, 1536)))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
model.load_weights(top_model_weights_path)
print("top model loaded")
prediction_proba = model.predict_proba(features)
prediction_classes = model.predict_classes(features)
print(prediction_proba)
print(prediction_classes)
print("original file names")
print(validation_generator.filenames)
```

the question is that how should the different prediction be saved in one single file. i have tried creating a for loop for file but not sure how it should work? it would be nice if some one could give hints for the goals defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Predicting and saving**

```
i = 0
maximumPredictions = ??
for x,y in generator: #if the generator doesn't have y, use only "for x in..."
    predictions = model.predict(x)
    numpy.save('predictions/prediction' + str(i) +".npy", predictions)
    i+=1

    if i == maximumPredictions:
        break;
```

**Loading and processing**

```
files = [name for name in os.listdir('predictions')]
for file in files:
    prediction = numpy.load('predictions/"+file)

    #do what you want with the loaded predictions.
```

Comment: in the for loop for predicting and saving, by generator do you mean validation_generator? and by model.predict do you mean the model.predict_generator?

Comment: Any generator you have. It can be `validation_generator`. But no, it's `predict` indeed.

Comment: it made my original code more slower to execute. it's making a lot of predictions for only 3 images which should not be the case

Comment: We can't really control what the generator outputs. At most, you can check if it has the `len(generator)` defined. Then you could use a shuffled range of indices to make the loop with `x,y = generator[index]`.